# Visual Studio 2019 fails to start due of side by side configuration

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2019

I installed Visual Studio 2019 16.3 and seems that I got error regarding side by side configuration. In event viewer I saw:

> Activation context generation failed for "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe".Error in manifest or
>   policy file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Automation\dsref80.dll.MANIFEST" on
>   line 0. Invalid Xml syntax.

What's the solution ?

Comment: The first line of that file should be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`. Is it?

Comment: What file are you referring to?

Comment: Problem solved by restart and reinstall